# boost::interprocess::timed_receive() never returns if sending process halts

Tags: c++, winapi, boost, boost-interprocess

I thought that calling timed_receive() would just time out in this case, but instead it gets stuck attempting to lock a mutex.

So is there a function that I can call on my que, before attempting to receive data, which tells me if the sending process has died or is halted?

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic method to know whether the counter-party, died, halted, partially locked (eg one of the threads is in an infinite loop), playing possum, or just being adversarial. If the counter-party is cooperative, you can communicate with heartbeats and rely on them to decide if it responsive.

The fact that your program is "stuck" attempting to lock a mutex (are you sure that that's the case?) can indicate that,

- the queue is empty, and the timeout value hasn't expired
- you've run into a deadlock scenario.

The timed_receive succeeds, times out, or throws as expected:

```
bool timed_receive(void * buffer, std::size_t buffer_size, 
                   std::size_t & recvd_size, unsigned int & priority, 
                   const boost::posix_time::ptime & abs_time);
```

> Receives a message from the message queue. The message is stored in
>   buffer "buffer", which has size "buffer_size". The received message
>   has size "recvd_size" and priority "priority". If the message queue is
>   empty the receiver retries until time "abs_time" is reached. Returns
>   true if the message has been successfully sent. Returns false if
>   timeout is reached. Throws interprocess_error on error.

Also make sure you pass an **absolute** timeout value.

Comment: Okay, this may have just been a misunderstanding on my part.  I had paused the sender in the debugger to test the timeout.  I expected that the receiver would then time out and exit.  But i think getting stuck in the shared mutex actually makes sense: the sender is still alive but not responding.  If instead i kill the sender, the timeout does happen as expected.

Comment: @DavidM.Cotter Glad to hear!